# Angular Unit Testing: How to unit test subscription inside ngOnInIt()?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Component to be tested:

```
export class ComponentDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
     ngOnInit() {

            this.componentDetailsService.currentProperties.subscribe((data) => {
                this.loader.hideLoader();    
                 this.showPopup = data.showPopup;
         .....more code....
    }
```

**Spec:**

```
class ComponentDetailsServiceStub {
  defaultProperties ={       
    showToolbar: false,        
    showPopup: true, //show popup is set to true here       
    refresh: false,
  };

    propertiesSource = new BehaviorSubject(this.defaultProperties);
  currentProperties = this.propertiesSource.asObservable();

  setDefaultCancelClicked(){}
}


it('should set showPopup to correct value', () => {

    componentDetailsService.propertiesSource.next({         
      showToolbar: true,         
      showPopup: false, // show popup is set to false          
      refresh: false,

    }); 

    expect(subject.showPopup).toBe(true) ///this always passes

   });
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve]; how is this wired up? I wouldn't test the `showPopup` property, I'd test *whether the popup is showing*. Also you may need a `detectChanges`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to write so many steps to pass as Observable.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
....

class ComponentDetailsServiceStub {
  defaultProperties ={       
    showToolbar: false,        
    showPopup: true, //show popup is set to true here       
    refresh: false,
  };
  currentProperties = of(defaultProperties); // will convert to Observable
  setDefaultCancelClicked(){}
}
```

And your test case can be:

```
it('should set showPopup to correct value', () => {
    subject.ngOnInit(); // jasmine will internally call subscribe on stub service created and return the stub value assigned.
    expect(subject.showPopup).toBe(true);
   });
```